# i cant inject ngmaterial on my angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to inject material.js in my angularJS but I have this error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24HashMapProvider%20%3C-%20%24%24HashMap%20%3C-%20%24%24animateQueue%20%3C-%20%24animate%20%3C-%20%24compile%20%3C-%20%24mdUtil%20%3C-%20%24mdTheming%20%3C-%20%24%24animateQueue

This is my code in :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="SRC/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="SRC/Bootstrap/css/font-awesome.css" />
<script src="SRC/AngularJs/AngularJs.js"></script>
<script src="SRC/JQuery/JQuery.js"></script>
<script src="SRC/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="SRC/AngularJs/Angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.4/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-aria.js"></script>

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.4/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.0-rc4/angular-material.layouts.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And this is my module:

```
var routeApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngSanitize','ngMaterial']);
```

If someone can help me.

Comment: check if your dependencies are loaded in right order

Comment: You should load the same modules versions that match to your angularjs file - I see version `1.6.4`, `1.1.4` and `1.4.0` - It can't be good. Make sure that `Angular-route.min.js` is also the same version as angularjs

Comment: @AlonEitan for angular-material `v1.1.4` is latest I guess.. but I agree with other version mismatches

Comment: @tanmay Take a look [at the error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$$HashMapProvider%20%3C-%20$$HashMap%20%3C-%20$$animateQueue%20%3C-%20$animate%20%3C-%20$compile%20%3C-%20$mdUtil%20%3C-%20$mdTheming%20%3C-%20$$animateQueue)  - I see `$animate` there, so it's probably the first (And perhaps the last) step to fix this error

Comment: Thanks guys , The problem came from my versions, resolved :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem came from my versions, resolved :D

it works like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="SRC/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="SRC/Bootstrap/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <script src="SRC/JQuery/JQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="SRC/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.4/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-aria.js"></script>

    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.4/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.0-rc4/angular-material.layouts.css" rel="stylesheet">
```